# Function get_locale always returns en_US in plugin?

Tags: plugins, language, plugin-polylang

I have the following problem developing a WordPress theme and I am here to ask you.
While using get_locale() in one of the plugin, its always returns the same en_US . Even though the language set if fr_FR.
To change the language i am using polylang plugin.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using with us? It would be good to know which filter or action you're hooking into when calling `get_locale()` and whether this happens in the admin or the front end. What does `pll_current_language()` return?

Comment: When using 'pll_current_language()' its return call to undefined function pll_current_language(), as this pll_current_language() is of polylang plugin.

Comment: I am using get_locale() inside on of my class function. The code i am using in  Currency switcher woocommerce [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/currency-switcher-woocommerce) currency-switcher-woocommerce\includes\class-alg-wc-currency-switcher.php line 125

Comment: Are you sure that the language is set? Because `get_locale()` always returns en_US if the language is not set. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_locale/#source in line 70

Comment: Yes i am sure, as i can see the lang attribute is different i.e fr_FR

Comment: Is there any function which applys to the filter ["locale"](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/locale/) or is the constant `WPLANG` defined in your wp-config?

Comment: No function is applied to filter "locale" and also `WPLANG` is also not defined

Comment: It looks like get_locale() in any plugin file is returning the same en_US locale, as i have tested it with contact form 7 plugin too

Comment: When exactly do you call get_locale()? According to the last part of [this article](https://polylang.pro/doc/developpers-how-to/#language-load) you have to wait until the action `pll_language_defined` is fired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71857/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-ahendwh2).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Would be helpful if you could post the result! :D